# How to split in aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this code and this one has more than one data from the database

so my expected output is

1.line1

2.line2

but with this code i get

**1.line12.line2**

but the data from the database have nextline on it.

this is the code

```
 <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
 <ItemTemplate>

<%# Eval("News_data") %>

 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

from this database

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TDBSConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [news], [news_date],[news_data] FROM [ibsi.news]">
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is the sample pics.

[image: this is the DB]

this is the output

[image: Ouput]

when i use pre tag

[image]

Comment: Is it showing \n in the data between line1 and line2 ?

Comment: no its just a space between them

Comment: Could you please expand your code for showing data? Where is this `Eval` used, is it a repeater, or gridview?

Comment: When you said **have this code and this one has more than one data from the database**. Does it mean you have two records or one record contain multiple line ?

Comment: Can you show the ItemTemplate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily replace it as that's normally (you own the database, so you will know better) a hidden character like **Line Feed** char...

if it is, try this:

```
<%# Eval("News_data").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br/>") %>
```

This happens for example if you are grabbing the data from a multirow textbox without convert it before.

`\n\r` is the same as (chr)13 + (chr)10 witch means LF ([Line Feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed)), CR ([Carriage Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)).

Comment: \n is not appearing in the data as per the comments in question section

Comment: `\n` is an hidden char, you will not see it unless you copy paste the data into a text editor and ask it to display non-printable chars.

Comment: @PankajGarg even in case of space it's still a simple matter of `.Replace(" ", "<br/>")` so this answer is the most correct one.

Comment: i tried but didnt work.. i tried changing the condition into space still no luck

Comment: @Shadow We cannot simply replace the space with new line. Is it acceptable ?

Comment: @Pankaj of course we can - suppose you have string "hello world" and you want it displayed in the browser in two lines. Replacing the space with `<br />` is perfectly valid and the most simple solution.

Comment: @Bert hmm.. maybe Adrian answer (now deleted for some reason so you can't see it) was correct after all. If you have `<%# Eval("News_data") %><br />` meaning adding `<br />` to the ItemTemplate, do you get the desired output?

Comment: @Shadow, Intentionally OP donot want to break two words in two lines. OP want to show two lines in correct format. balexandre -  +1  for \r\n I checked at my side. For new lines it shows these chars.

Comment: @shadow treid that also but still no luck. i tried using tag <pre> and i got it but there are margins around it and i think i prefer other solution.

Comment: Did you try with \r\n  in replace as told by @balexandre ?

Comment: @Bert what is the raw data? Can you copy and paste a sample exactly as it is into your question? Maybe some fancy character is the culprit here.

Comment: i'll post a pic of the database data and the output on my screen

Comment: attached above are the pics. one the 2nd pic i use the one that @balexandre solution

Comment: got the answer. this one is correct. i researched and i used "/r" because it can be /r/n. thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some manipulation, put a template field in the gridview and a span inside

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span ID="spnHtml" runat="server">
        </span> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now in the RowDataBound manipulate the data.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl spnHtml = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Row.FindControl("spnHtml");           
        string sHtml = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "YourDbColumnName");
        spnHtml.InnerHtml = sHtml;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not literal and why span ?